# doctrine query builder select from table which is not entity table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I am struggling to find a way to use query builder to select data from a table which is not a table of some entity. method ->from() takes only class name (entity name) as a parameter. 
something like:

```
$qb->select('t.id')
   ->from('table_not_entity_name')
   ->andWhere('t.isActive = :isActive')
   ->setParameter('isActive', 1);
```

I also need to join a table of entity to an another table.

```
$qb->select('category.id')
    ->join("t.table_name", 'category')
    ->distinct();
```

Is there a way?

Comment: if is not mapped with any entity you can't use as ORM but only as DBAL. You can't map it with an entity class?

Comment: yep, I can't since it the custom table outside of any entity. I should wrap it then in a new 'fake' entity I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with DQL, you can use [NativeQuery](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html).

The comment in function 'from()' at QueryBuilder class says that:

> Creates and adds a query root corresponding to the entity identified
>   by the given alias, forming a cartesian product with any existing
>   query roots.

Is specific for an entity.